# I try to get following::* in xpath but the data is repeat whenever it have more than one tagname on it

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, scrapy

I try to get all the following data below after some tagname, but the thing is, it will show everything and repeat to show it if it have more than one tagname for example:

```
<ul>
<li>
<p>new or worsening <a href=""/cg/chronic-cough.html"" data-type=""auto"">cough</a>, <a href=""/cg/asthma.html"" data-type=""auto"">wheezing</a>, trouble breathing;</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>blue lips, blue colored fingers or toes;</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>easy bruising, unusual bleeding, purple or red spots under your skin;</p>
</li>
<li>
<p><a href=""/cg/bradycardia.html"" data-type=""auto"">slow heart rate</a>, weak pulse, <a href=""/cg/syncope.html"" data-type=""auto"">fainting</a>, slow breathing (breathing may stop);</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>kidney problems--little or no urination, swelling in your feet or ankles, feeling tired or short of breath; or</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>low calcium level--muscle <a href=""/cg/muscle-spasm-aftercare-instructions.html"" data-type=""auto"">spasms</a> or contractions, numbness or tingling;</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>low magnesium--dizziness, irregular heartbeats, feeling jittery, muscle cramps, muscle spasms, cough or choking feeling; or</p>
</li>
<li>
<p><a href=""/cg/hypokalemia.html"" data-type=""auto"">low potassium</a> level--leg cramps, <a href=""/cg/constipation.html"" data-type=""auto"">constipation</a>, fluttering in your chest, increased thirst or urination, muscle weakness or limp feeling.</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

for example in code above, it will show the all inside ul, and all inside li, and all inside a, so I will get 3 of the same text. I actually just want to get all inside ull without repeat the other. is there a way? thank you

Comment: where is your code? Please provide a [mre] and as well as what it is your goal or intended output is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fixed this by skip the data that I already take so it's not overlap

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as if you want `following-sibling::*` rather than `following::*`.